# Querying objects in dynamic properties or arrays with elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

For some reason I simply haven't been able to wrap my head around being able to do this in elastic search (I'm having a hard time making sense of some of the documentation; it feels like there are 15 ways to do this and I can't figure out any of them) but say I have the following object:

```
{
    "name": "Me",
    "favorites": [
        { title: "Stackoverflow", url: "www.stackoverflow.com" },
        { title: "Google", url: "www.google.com" }
    ],
    "stuff": {
        "fdjalja": { "property": "yes" },
        "nvbdfgd": { "property": "no" }
    }
}
```

1. How do I query inside of the array for, say, title == "Google"? I know I can hit nested objects really easy but simply adding a dot but when it's array I can't figure it out.
2. How do I query inside of the stuff object where the keys are dynamic? So I can search for property == "yes"?

Answer (score 0):

I got a [`nested` query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html#query-dsl-nested-query) to work like this:

Notice that I put `"type":"nested"` in the mapping:

```
DELETE /test_index

PUT /test_index
{
   "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 1
   },
   "mappings": {
      "doc": {
         "properties": {
            "favorites": {
               "type": "nested", 
               "properties": {
                  "title": {
                     "type": "string"
                  },
                  "url": {
                     "type": "string"
                  }
               }
            },
            "name": {
               "type": "string"
            },
            "stuff": {
               "properties": {
                  "fdjalja": {
                     "properties": {
                        "property": {
                           "type": "string"
                        }
                     }
                  },
                  "nvbdfgd": {
                     "properties": {
                        "property": {
                           "type": "string"
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Then added the doc:

```
PUT /test_index/doc/1
{
    "name": "Me",
    "favorites": [
        { "title": "Stackoverflow", "url": "www.stackoverflow.com" },
        { "title": "Google", "url": "www.google.com" }
    ],
    "stuff": {
        "fdjalja": { "property": "yes" },
        "nvbdfgd": { "property": "no" }
    }
}
```

And then a nested match on `"favorites.title"` returns the doc:

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
   "query": {
      "nested": {
         "path": "favorites",
         "query": {
            "match": {
               "favorites.title": "google"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
...
{
   "took": 46,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 1.4054651,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1.4054651,
            "_source": {
               "name": "Me",
               "favorites": [
                  {
                     "title": "Stackoverflow",
                     "url": "www.stackoverflow.com"
                  },
                  {
                     "title": "Google",
                     "url": "www.google.com"
                  }
               ],
               "stuff": {
                  "fdjalja": {
                     "property": "yes"
                  },
                  "nvbdfgd": {
                     "property": "no"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

You can query for the dynamic, non-array properties by using the path:

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
   "query": {
      "match": {
         "stuff.fdjalja.property": "yes"
      }
   }
}
```